# AngularJs formatting extremely small decimal numbers (1e-8)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have extremely small number, i.e. 0.00000001 - if I simply do `{{ mynumber }}` I get output of `1e-8`.

The other alternative is doing `{{ mynumber | number:8 }}` which would print out `0.00000001`. However then in case I have `0.1`, it would print out `0.10000000`.

Is there a way to format floats in javascript / angular so that 0s are only appended as needed?

Comment: Sounds like you should write your own filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this filter:

```
app.filter('formatNumber', function() {
    return function(value) {
        return value.toFixed(20).replace(/0+$/, '')
    };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{ mynumber | formatNumber }}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n0kkqdym/)**

---

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that because of rounding errors the result of the given filter is not always correct.
That's why I made a new one:

```
app.filter('formatNumber', function() {
    return function(value) {
        var v = value.toString(),
            m = v.match(/(.*)e-(\d)/);
        return m ? '0.' + new Array(parseInt(m[2], 10)).join('0') + m[1].replace('.', '') : v;      
    };
});
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n0kkqdym/2/)** (including a comparsion between the two solutions. Here you can also see why you should prefer the second filter).